# Mapping two dimensional array to one dimensional array with indexes

Tags: ruby

I have 2d array like this:

```
ary = [
  ["Source", "attribute1", "attribute2"],
  ["db", "usage", "value"],
  ["import", "usage", "value"],
  ["webservice", "usage", "value"]
]
```

I want to pull out the following in hash:

```
{1 => "db", 2 => "import", 3 => "webservice"} // keys are indexes or outer 2d array
```

I know how to get this by looping trough 2d array. But since I'm learning ruby I thought I could do it with something like this

```
ary.each_with_index.map {|element, index| {index => element[0]}}.reduce(:merge)
```

This gives me :

```
{0=> "Source", 1 => "db", 2 => "import", 3 => "webservice"}
```

How do I get rid of 0 element from my output map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write:

```
Hash[ary.drop(1).map.with_index(1) { |xs, idx| [idx, xs.first] }]
#=> {1=>"db", 2=>"import", 3=>"webservice"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ary.drop(1)` drops the first element, returns the rest.

You could build the hash directly without the merge reduction using `each_with_object`

```
ary.drop(1)
  .each_with_object({})
  .with_index(1) { |((source,_,_),memo),i| memo[i] = source }
```

Or map to tuples and send to the `Hash[]` constructor.

```
Hash[ ary.drop(1).map.with_index(1) { |(s,_,_),i| [i, s] } ]
```